# Why I get empty array sometimes by using findAll?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use `BeautifulSoup` to get YouTube video id.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    # BeautifulSoup get video id
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + trailerCnName
    request = requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
    vids = soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'})
    print(vids)
```

I'm sure `trailerCnName` has value.

I test a lot of times, sometimes `print(vids)` has value, but sometimes it is empty array.

Even I change time sleep second to 5, it is still not working.

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Could the website be blocking your requests?

Comment: Not every time I get empty array, so I don't think so they block my request dynamiclly.

Comment: It could be after you’ve sent multiple requests in a short period of time, for example. The `sleep()` is unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if `sleep()` is not working, how do I avoid request many times in a short period of time ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get an empty array, check the URL's HTML code by doing the inspect element to see whether the  tag is available or not. Probably the class "yt-uix-tile-link" is a dynamic one. Hence, you don't get that every time.

Comment: Hmm... dynamic class... , let me check the html tag again.

Comment: Also, please be sure whether the server is blocking your request or not. In that case, also you will get empty results. Although I believe in those scenarios the code will throw some exception/error.